# codeigniter - dependent dropdown jquery does not work when url have other characters at the end of class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

i have this codes of a dependent drop-down,

here is the jquery

```
<script>


    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      $("#PROV_ID").change(function() {
        var PROVID = {"PROVID" : $('#PROV_ID').val()};
        console.log(PROVID);

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          data: PROVID,
          url: "<?php base_url(); ?>Employees/dependent_dropdown",

          success: function(data){
              var select = $('#CT_ID');
              select.html('');
              $.each(data, function(i, option){
                  select.append("<option value='"+option.CT_ID+"'>"+option.CITY+"</option>");
              });
          }
         });
       });
     });


</script>
```

and the controller is

```
   public function dependent_dropdown()
   {
       if(isset($_POST['PROVID']))
       {

            $data = $_POST['PROVID'];
            $this->output
            ->set_content_type("application/json")
            ->set_output(json_encode($this->Employees_Model->getType($data)));
       }
   }
```

the url of that is http://localhost/TLC_HR/employees/add_view

but for example i put something on the url for example http://localhost/TLC_HR/employees/add_view/ID_NUMBER then the jquery will have an error of `TypeError: $(…).tooltip is not a function`

how do i fix it so that incase i need this function and i need to use the `$this->uri->segment()` function, i can use them at the same time

Comment: not working brother

Comment: Show us your route config for this url.

Comment: where can i find that

Comment: In application/config/routes.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your `application/config/routes.php` so that `add_view()` accepts extra parameter.

Add this to your `routes.php`:

```
$route['employees/add_view/(:num)'] = 'employees/add_view/$1';
```

Modify your `add_view()`:

```
public function add_view($id_number = null)
{
    // do something with $id_number parameter

    // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: @kev_m Sorry misread which url you want extra parameter in. I've updated the answer.

Comment: javascript still not working with additional url segment